# Can we have a common file having the script for background image so that all the webpages can be linked to that?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a common code file in HTML? For instance we are creating some web pages using HTML and need to set a common background. But after it is specified it is too tiresome to change it in every page. It would be quick if they all shared a script to a common file having the code for background color. The following code's location will be shared by all other web pages. So is this possible?

```
<html>
<style>
  body
      {
       background-image:url("Brown_wall.jpg");
      }
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: just put your css in a separate file, and link to it inside the `<head>`.

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create a CSS file with your background image and link it to your html. This will work for every file in the current directory. Anything above or below will need to be modified just a tad.

Answer (score 1):

The `link` tag is what you're looking for.  This [article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Including_a_stylesheet) goes over the specifics of adding stylesheets to your HTML where you would only have to change that one file to see the change reflected in every page that includes it.  It also makes your HTML files shorter and less redundant!  Here's an example.  You'd save these files in the same directory.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hello <span>world</span>!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
p span {
  color: green;
}
```